# Spring Webflow accessing flow scope variable that is created using context.getFlowScope().put(key, Obj) in the JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, el, spring-webflow

I am new to Spring Webflow and Here is my question:

I have created a flowscope variable in my Action Class as below :

```
public void getStatusValue(HttpServletRequest req, RequestContext context) {
    //This 'appStatus' value will return either "yes" or"no"
    String status = req.getSession(true).getAttribute("appStatus");
    if("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(status)){
        context.getFlowScope().put("applicationStarted" , "yes");
    } else {
        context.getFlowScope().put("applicationStarted","no");
    }
}
```

I make a call to this method from the xml file using

```
<on-entry>
    <evaluate expression = "Action.getStarted(FlowRequestContext)"/>
</on-entry>
```

The getStarted() method will make a call to getStatus() method.
I was able to print the value using

```
context.getFlowScope().get("applicationStarted")
```

and it printed in the action class

Now, on JSP, i am trying to retrieve the value of "applicationStarted" variable this way

```
<script type=text/javascript">
var status = ${applicationStarted};
alert(status);
if(status == "yes")
//do something

else
//do something
```

The issue is: 1. The alert doesnt get printed at all
and somehow the if condition inside the jsp doesnt execute , so i dont get the logic working

can someone guide me on this?

Edit:
after searching, I learnt that the webflow variables cant be accessed by the JavaScript directly, so I tried to use a `<c:set>` tag in jsp and tried to set this way:

```
<c:set var="applicationStarted" scope="session" value="     {applicationStarted"}"/>
```

an in the JavaScript :

```
var status = "<c:out value='${applicationStarted}'/>";
```

I still could not see the alert printed and the logic doesn't work.
I am sure I might be missing something on the syntax.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution for the above issue.
For others who ran into the same issue, here is the fix.

on the javascript, while accessing the variable using 
just provide the sessionScope like below:

```
var status = "<c:out value='${sessionScope.applicationStarted}'/>";
```

and the value of "status" will be populated

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there way to access ConversationScope variables? I tried ${conversationScope.var1} but it is neither returning anything nor throwing an error. Please help.